# Curl PHP requests in sequence

Tags: php, curl

Is there a way I can be notified when a curl request completes?  I'd like to start another request upon completion

```
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id='.$uids.'&include_entities=true');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: The `curl_exec` function call will stall your script execution until that very request is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL is "blocking" so when it's done you'll just move to the next line.
Simply call another URL after `$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to execute curl in asynchronous manner,
use [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) to parellel running multiple curl
(if network bandwidth is not a constraint)